# SSRS How to create a report with a drop down list were each option from the list will take them to a different report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I need to create a report using ssrs that will allow users to go into a main page and from there they will have a drop down listing 3 different reports to choose from. I have created 3 different stored procedures for each report needed. Ive been looking at examples but everyone talks about sub reports but I don't think I need that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think you don't need sub reports?

Comment: @TabAlleman from looking at examples sub reports may display 2 or 3 reports in the same page. I would like for the user to see only the report they are picking. So the first thing they see when they open the report is the drop down list, once they pick what they want to view it will take them to their parameters page and then run the report.

Comment: That's only one way you can use subreports.   You can also just give your report one sub-report, and use the parameter to determine which report is used for the sub-report.

Comment: Why not just create a folder to hold the three reports on the report server?

Comment: Another option is to add three text boxes to your main report and use the Action property to set up a link to the relevant report